# Dynamically Modify s2member Options

Tags: plugins, functions, s2member

With the s2member plugin, whenever you want new posts protected, you have to manually go into the plugin options and add the post ID to a list of comma separated post IDs.  When you save anything at all in the options, the plugin saves it all in a gigantic record in the wp_options table under the option name, ws_plugin__s2member_options.  So I figured I would write a function that grabs the post ID and updates that record.  It works fine except there is some 'checksum value' that is generated and placed in there that is dependent on the options.  So every time a post is saved, the options are updated in the database... but the plugin checks and sees that they've been changed because of this checksum value - and then it reverts every single setting in the configuration to the original defaults.  I was told that I could call the function or hook for that, but no luck at all.  Anyone familiar with this plugin enough to tell me how to just remove that stupid pointless checksum/check?  I say it's stupid and pointless because if someone gains access to my database and changes those options, I think the options are the least of my worries.

Comment: There are several possibilities - either for achieving your larger purpose or for doing so by the means you describe - but to answer your question it might be a time-saver or helpful in other ways if you could provide exactly what S2 Member support told you, including any direct or implicit references to the files or functions involved. I haven't worked with S2 Member in years, but is was replete with action hooks and filters.

Comment: They said to use a hook or function, but not much more than that.  I use functions but am not that experienced with hooks and classes yet.  Anyway, here's their exact comment: 'Use s2M's function (I don't know which it is) to save cofiguration options after you change them, it will set the sum.

Alternatively (my lovely way) - change configurations at each run of the plugin, after they was read. It's easy to do at the s2M's hook, that runs after initial start of the plugin (still I can't remember the exactly hook, sorry). '